# How do I prevent JHipster from automatically committing to my Git repo?

Tags: jhipster

When I run `jhipster import-jdl`, it automatically commits to my Git repository. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `--skip-git` option

See doc: https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#3